# Bad Word Filter, how to combine with URL Replace

Tags: php, jquery, filter, replace, cpu-word

I have two scripts - javascript and php..

this cleans the url

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.search-form').submit(function() {
        window.location.href = "/file_"+ $('.search-form input:text').val() + ".html";
     return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

this is the bad word filter

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['search']))
    {
    $search=$_GET['search'];

    if(is_array($badwords) && sizeof($badwords) >0)
    {
    foreach($badwords as $theword)
    $search = ereg_replace($theword,"haha",$search);
    }
    $search=preg_replace("/\s+/"," ",$search);

    $keyword = str_replace(" ", "+", $search);
    }

    else
    {
    $keyword = str_replace(" ", "+a", $keyword);
    }
    ?>
```

how can i combine this two scripts and replace the bad word in the url with "haha"?

Comment: just a word of caution: bad language filters are usually a bad idea as they too often corrupt valid uses and those trying to get around them can simply turn to 1337 speak and use special characters to get the message across. Just two examples: assignment and ashita.org, since they both contain frequently flagged words, you'll get something like hahaignment and ahahaa.org.

Comment: Just wait until someone asks about Pen Island :O

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect in the PHP

First, the form:

```
<form action="somefile.php">
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" value="" placeholder="Enter here..." />
<button>Search</button>
</form>
```

Second:

```
// somefile.php
  if (isset($_GET['search'])){
    $search=$_GET['search'];
    if(count($badwords)){
    foreach($badwords as $theword)
      $search = ereg_replace($theword,"haha",$search);
    }
    $search=preg_replace("/\s+/"," ",$search);
    $keyword = str_replace(" ", "+", $search);
  } else {
    $keyword = str_replace(" ", "+a", $keyword);
  }
  // here you can do any checks with the search and redirect to anywhere
  if (strlen($keyword)){
    header("location: /file_{$keyword}.html");
  }
```

Or you can use ajax to check and clean the keyword:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.search-form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", dataType: "HTML",
             url: "clean.php", 
             data: { search: $('.search-form input:text').val()},
             success: function(response){
               if (response.length > 0) {
                 window.location.href = "/" + response;
               }
             }
   });
</script>
```

Clean.php:

```
  if (isset($_GET['search'])){
    $search=$_GET['search'];
    if(count($badwords)){
    foreach($badwords as $theword)
      $search = ereg_replace($theword,"haha",$search);
    }
    $search=preg_replace("/\s+/"," ",$search);
    $keyword = str_replace(" ", "+", $search);
  } else {
    $keyword = str_replace(" ", "+a", $keyword);
  }
  // here you can do any checks with the search and redirect to anywhere
  if (strlen($keyword)){
    echo("file_{$keyword}.html");
  } ?>
```

You can look for more information about ajax / post / get (jQuery) in:

```
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/
```